# JMX Agent Server - launch agent with SSL attributes set inside Programme

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate, jmx

Introduction - I have a test JMX agent/server & JMX client. Both are having SSL communication (2way) via command-line launching time JVM attribute set (with -D option).

Agent/Server has `serverkeystore.jks`, and `servertruststore.jks`. Client has `clientkeystore.jks` & `clienttruststore.jks. servertruststore.jks` has imported `client certificate. clienttruststore.jks` has imported `server certificate`.
Note: jks are self signed (produced from keytool )

This is okay and working when both are launched from the command line with VM arguments

```
[ Agent/server side VM args in cmnd line  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:\Task\serverkeystore.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=serverpass -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Task\servertruststore.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=servertrustpass -Djdk.tls.server.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djavax.net.debug=all. ]
```

Working Okay

```
[ Client side VM args in cmd line -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Task\clienttruststore.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=clienttrustpass -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:\Task\clientkeystore.jks" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=clientpass -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 ]
```

Working Okay

Objective - Using the same jks files as in the command line above, The requirement is now, not to use VM args as command line, rather set those from inside the program, so that those are not visible in deployment production time in commands like "ps -fu".

Note: Client-side and JMX calls are working okay when I use System.setProperty for all client VM args from inside client prog in client-side and connect the Agent/Server which is launched with VM args in the command line.

So the Issue is - For Agent /Server-side, although after all Vm args are set in System.setProperty, getProperty is returning values that are set, on server-side some extra code needs to be written. So when I google and found some code snippets which include - `LocateRegistry.createRegistry`, `JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer`, those are done. but somehow during SSL handshake its throwing error like :

<< Error >>

```
Fatal (UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE): Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
```

<< Stack trace in summary >>

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:29.834 IST|TrustStoreManager.java:112|trustStore is: C:\Task\servertruststore.jks
trustStore type is: pkcs12
trustStore provider is:
the last modified time is: Mon Sep 20 19:41:21 IST 2021
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:29.836 IST|TrustStoreManager.java:311|Reload the trust store
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:29.993 IST|TrustStoreManager.java:318|Reload trust certs
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:29.994 IST|TrustStoreManager.java:323|Reloaded 1 trust certs
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:29.999 IST|X509TrustManagerImpl.java:79|adding as trusted certificates (
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "02 23 71 B2",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withDSA",

...
...

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:30.001 IST|SSLContextImpl.java:1088|keyStore is : C:\Task\serverkeystore.jks
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:30.004 IST|SSLContextImpl.java:1089|keyStore type is : pkcs12
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:30.005 IST|SSLContextImpl.java:1091|keyStore provider is :
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:30.006 IST|SSLContextImpl.java:1126|init keystore
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:30.074 IST|SSLContextImpl.java:1149|init keymanager of type SunX509
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:30.137 IST|SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:164|found key for : serverkey (
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "19 09 4F 95",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withDSA",

...
...

javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:30.137 IST|SSLContextImpl.java:115|trigger seeding of SecureRandom
javax.net.ssl|ALL|01|main|2021-09-27 15:11:31.572 IST|SSLContextImpl.java:119|done seeding of SecureRandom

system properties are set

Create RMI registry on port 9999

Server url is service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:9999/jmxrmi

Start the RMI connector server


javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0F|RMI TCP Accept-0|2021-09-27 15:11:31.830 IST|SSLConfiguration.java:457|System property jdk.tls.client.SignatureSchemes is set to 'null'

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0F|RMI TCP Accept-0|2021-09-27 15:11:31.838 
IST|SSLConfiguration.java:457|System property jdk.tls.server.SignatureSchemes is set to 'null'

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|15|RMI TCP Connection(2)-172.24.160.1|2021-09-27 15:11:31.854 IST|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:488|Raw read (
  0000: 4A 52 4D 49 00                                     JRMI.
)

javax.net.ssl|ERROR|15|RMI TCP Connection(2)-172.24.160.1|2021-09-27 15:11:31.857 IST|TransportContext.java:341|Fatal (UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE): Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:451)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:175)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1418)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1324)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:829)

javax.net.ssl|ALL|15|RMI TCP Connection(2)-172.24.160.1|2021-09-27 15:11:31.857 IST|SSLSessionImpl.java:784|Invalidated session:  Session(1632735691832|SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|15|RMI TCP Connection(2)-172.24.160.1|2021-09-27 15:11:31.865 IST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:71|WRITE: TLS12 alert(unexpected_message), length = 2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|15|RMI TCP Connection(2)-172.24.160.1|2021-09-27 15:11:31.866 IST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:85|Raw write (
  0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 0A                               .......
)

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|15|RMI TCP Connection(2)-172.24.160.1|2021-09-27 15:11:31.867 IST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1638|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|15|RMI TCP Connection(2)-172.24.160.1|2021-09-27 15:11:31.868 IST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1657|close the SSL connection (initiative)


javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|15|RMI TCP Connection(3)-172.24.160.1|2021-09-27 15:11:31.880 IST|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:488|Raw read (
  0000: 4A 52 4D 49 00                                     JRMI.
)

javax.net.ssl|ERROR|15|RMI TCP Connection(3)-172.24.160.1|2021-09-27 15:11:31.881 IST|TransportContext.java:341|Fatal (UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE): Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
        at 
java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:451)
```

<< Agent / server code snippets >>

```
    boolean pwd_auth = false;
    boolean pwd_auth = false;
    boolean ssl_auth = true;
    String strPort = "9999";
    int port = 9999;
    env = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate", String.valueOf(pwd_auth));
    System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl", String.valueOf(ssl_auth));
    System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl" , String.valueOf(ssl_auth));
    System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth", String.valueOf(ssl_auth));
    System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.port",strPort);
    System.setProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port",strPort);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", Config.keyStoreFile);// "C:\\Task\\serverkeystore.jks";
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", Config.keyStorePwd );
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore" , Config.trustStoreFile ); // "C:\\Task\\servertruststore.jks";
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword" , Config.trustStorePwd);
    System.setProperty("jdk.tls.server.protocols", Config.protocol); // TLSv1.2

    env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_SERVER_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, new SslRMIServerSocketFactory()); // if i comment this, then no exception in trace, but then during client connection, server will not respond, client gets failure in connection.
    
    echo("system properties are set");
    echo("Create RMI registry on port " + port); // system out only
    LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
    mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    String strUrl = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:"+port+"/jmxrmi";
    JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(strUrl);
    echo ("Server url is " + strUrl);
    JMXConnectorServer cs = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(url, env, mbs);
    echo("Start the RMI connector server");
    cs.start();

    Hello mbean = new Hello(); // MBean registering now
    name = new ObjectName(Config.oname);
    mbs.registerMBean(mbean, name);
```

```
Note: For VM args in the command line, this system.setProperty, env, createRegistry, newJMXConnectorServer calls are not required, Only MBeans registration is enough.
```

So, from the stack trace, it shows, the jks files are read with passwords provided in `System.setProperty` calls. so this setProperty is working. but somehow something more code statements are required or I am missing something in code statements.

Can anyone suggest any improvements, changes to be done to make this happen?